# Redirect if date in URL is later than current month

Tags: javascript, arrays, url

I am trying to display a page if today's date is current or in the past by reading the current pages URL and looking for keywords. For example,

Sample URL: http://www.website.com/blog/2019/october.html

I would like to write a script that finds the month ("October") and year (2019) from the URL of the page and determines if it is current or in the past. If it is in the future, it will redirect them to an error page, current or past will let them through. The purpose of this is I am pre-publishing pages that I don't want the user to be able to access until it is current content.

I am currently using window.location.href.includes to find a value in the URL, then compare against an array using a loop to return a month and year number. My code so far:

```
// Sample URL: http://www.website.com/blog/2019/october.html

var monthName = ["january", "february", "march", "april", "may", "june", "july", "august", "september", "october", "november", "december"];
var monthNum = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];

for (i = 0; i < monthName.length; i++) {
    if (window.location.href.includes(monthName[i]) > 0) {
        var pageMonth = (monthNum[i]);
    }
    else {
    }
}
```

This will give me a result of 10. I was then going to do the same with the year, then make another statement that combines them into a date, then use *another* statement to determine if thatDate <= currentDate. Is there a better way to execute this?

This method is a mess and it seems like I might be missing something that makes this easier to achieve.

---

**UPDATE:** Thank you for all your responses. I have finished my code which is still preferable since it does not depend on the structure of the URL, instead it will just search it all in case I need to move files around or make this work somewhere else as well. I think it could definitely use some cleaning up (especially the two-digit month sections) but I wanted to post it here.

```
var d = new Date();
var monthTwoDigit = ("0" + (d.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
var monthName = ["january", "february", "march", "april", "may", "june", "july", "august", "september", "october", "november", "december"];
var monthNum = ["01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12"];

for (i = 00; i < monthName.length; i++) {
    if (window.location.href.includes(monthName[i]) > 0) {
        var pageMonth = monthNum[i];
    }
    else {
    }
}

for (i = 2019; i < 3000; i++) {
    if (window.location.href.includes(i) > 0) {
        var pageYear = (i);
    }
    else {
    }
}

var urlDate = "" + pageYear + pageMonth;
var actualDate = "" + d.getFullYear() + monthTwoDigit;

if (urlDate > actualDate) {
    window.location.replace("http://www.website.com/error.html");
}
else {
    document.write("SAFE");
}
```

Comment: That's about right, though you you need to think carefully about how you setup the dates for testing (e.g. set both to 00:00:00 on the first of the month, or set the URL date to 00:00:00 on the first of the following month and compare with Date.now(), etc.). I think this is more a code review question though, so perhaps off topic here.

Comment: That is definitely the part I am having trouble with. I'm just going to try and format it as best I can against new Date().getFullYear() and getMonth() so we'll see.

Comment: And sorry if off topic, it was less about reviewing code and more about other methods or suggestions to go about doing this.

Comment: this type of code will solve your problem

for eg let source: http://www.website.com/blog/2019/october.html

get currmonth and curryear from  var d = new Date();

now check

if(source.indexof(currmonth) > -1 && source.indexof(currmonth) > -1) {
  //than return your page
}

Comment: Don't post answers in comments, especially code @VarunkumarGande

Comment: yup @Domino, I will keep this in mind

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this code can be improved in a number of ways. Also, to compare dates we are going to use `Date` instance, which is built-in JS approach to deal with date and time.

```js
var monthName = ["january", "february", "march", "april", "may", "june", "july", "august", "september", "october", "november", "december"];
```

First of all, we don't need to list month numbers because we can use array indexes of the array above (from 0 to 11), it will give us the benefit in the future.

Now let's parse month and year from the URL. We are going to use regular expressions to write less code:

```js
const matches = window.location.href.match(/http:\/\/www.website.com\/blog\/([0-9]{4})\/([a-z]{3,})\.html/);

// String.prototype.match, which we used can give us null value if URL doesn't match our pattern, so we need to check it first. 
if (matches !== null) {
  const year = parseInt(matches[0]); // the first match of regular expression is the year
  const monthIndex = monthName.indexOf(matches[1]); // this should give us the number of month, from 0 to 11
  if (monthIndex !== -1) { // but we must continue only if month name in the URL is correct.
    const date = new Date(); // Get current date.

    // Now let's extract month and year from the current date.
    // date.getMonth() returns the current number of month from 0 to 11, just what we need.
    // date.getFullYear() obviously returns the current year number.
    // Let's use these methods and compare current date values with ones we've got from the URL:

    if (date.getFullYear() > year || (date.getFullYear() === year && date.getMonth() > monthIndex)) {
      // we're in the future, let's redirect:
      window.location.href = 'https://website.com/error.html';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: this is a great answer too; if I had 1 complaint its regarding the URL structure, which really is my fault for not specifying in my question that I would prefer to stay away from that since I'd like to use this in other areas. Something that just searches the entire URL regardless of its layout would work better for me, but for the question I posted about this is a great solution.

Comment: Oh, I see you. I missed the point a bit, I didn't see that you wrote about searching for keywords. Then the best way is to make keywords array and check for every occurrence in the URL. Although sometimes the month name found in the URL may not represent the actual month when publication was made, as well as the year.

Comment: I don't quite understand what are you trying to achieve, but if you have access to the entire page loading process then it's probably better to use [Last-Modified](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Last-Modified) HTTP header, for example, it gives you information about when the page was modified (or created if no modifications were made).

Comment: Thanks Andrey, see my code that I updated with at the end of the original post. That's where I am now and it seems to work pretty well, however no matter how I try to launch it, the page loads first and stays for about 1 second before the redirect kicks in. I am using $(document).ready(myFunction); in the script and I am linking the script in the head of the document after my jquery.min link. Can you think of a reason this would be happening?

Comment: In this particular code there are no interactions with DOM, so you don't need to wait it to load. You can place your script **before** loading jQuery and don't wrap it in $(document).ready() since there are no interactions with page elements.

Comment: But I am linking to my script: "script src="../../js/myscript.js"" in the header, and script is wrapped in a function that runs with document.ready. I would prefer to keep the external link instead of pasting the whole script in each html document if possible, is there a different way to do that?

Comment: No, I was just saying that you need to put the ```<script>``` tag above jquery. You can still load your script from an external file. If this code is just the part of your JS code, and there's something else going on inside the ```$(document).ready()```, consider moving your redirection code into a separate file and link it with ```<script>``` above jquery. It just will be loaded and executed before jquery and everything else, which is what you exactly need.

Comment: Ahhhhh I see what you mean- I removed the function aspect and now it works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. However it's better to use backend approach for such problems, because search engines and users with disabled javascript can simply avoid redirection.

Comment: Any idea's as to why this wouldn't be working at all in IE11? Other scripts are running ok. Edge also takes 1-2 seconds before it redirects...

Comment: Nope, I forgot those days when I’ve been optimizing something for IE, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it pretty much as you've specified. Clear, obvious logic is the easiest to maintain.

```js
function isFutureURL(url) {
  // Month name array
  let months = ["january", "february", "march", "april", "may", "june", "july", "august", "september", "october", "november", "december"];

  // Parse the URL for the year and month
  let b = url.split(/\/|\./);
  let y = b[6];
  let m = months.indexOf(b[7]);

  // Set URL date to 00:00:00 at start of URL month
  let urlDate = new Date(y, m, 1);

  // Return true if test date is after current date
  // I.e. it's the first of next month or greater
  return urlDate > Date.now();
}

['http://www.website.com/blog/2018/april.html',
 'http://www.website.com/blog/2019/october.html',
 'http://www.website.com/blog/2020/may.html'
].forEach(sampleURL => 
  console.log(sampleURL + '\n is in the future? ' + isFutureURL(sampleURL))
);
```

This assumes that the month and year will always be in the same place in the URL, you might want to consider options to make that more robust (e.g. look for a month name and valid year anywhere in the URL).

You also might want to do some validation of the URL and values of *y* and *m* to avoid the user seeing errors.

Comment: I expected direct date comparisons to make things more complicated, but the `(year:int, month:int, day:int)` constructor actually creates a date at the beginning of the day in the current timezone so it's perfect. Not bad!

Comment: this is a wonderful solution. my only reservation is what you said, that the URL keeps its structure. There are other areas of the site I would like to use this on and I would prefer a method that just searches the whole URL regardless of how it is structured.

Answer (score 0):

Use an if condition

For example, **let the source be: http://www.website.com/blog/2019/october.html**

**Get currMonthNo and curryear from**

`var d = new Date();`

and also get **srcMonthNo** from **sourceurl**

**Now check**

```
if(source.indexof(curryear) > -1 && currMonthNo <= srcMonthNo) {
  // Then return your conditional code
} else {
  // Return error message
}
```

Comment: That... really is an incomplete answer which adds nothing to what others have said.

Comment: this also looks for current year AND current month. If I am in September of this year, it should pass as well.

Comment: you have month numbers right?  so get currMonthNo and get SrcMonthNo,i have changed answer please look @Fablezim

Comment: The new code still doesn't work as it doesn't do proper year comparison.

Comment: Console and check

Comment: You have to get the year in same type as number

Comment: Send your code to me through link in codepen or w3 schools ,i will do that